# iOS unknown exception and crash report

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova, web-worker

We built an iOS application using Cordova/angular/ionic. The application is a photo application which uses web workers for background image processing.

After doing some image manipulation we are clearing all of our variables and memory is stable. Every so often the application gets hidden in the background and then when triggered using an external link it crashes randomly. I am getting the below crash report in xCode. The memory is stable in xCode and the application crashes before the "resume" iOS callback is called so xCode does not output any exception.

We believe this is something to do with Workers since the application crashes only after workers have been used, but we cannot find the memory leak or the lingering pointer.

We are also getting something like this in xCode (randomly) when we do worker.postMessage to a ready worker.

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x397d0614> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x397d086c> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

We don't know if the above error is connected to the above crash or not.

Has anyone had any similar issues?

```
Incident Identifier: D15A92CA-1384-41A4-86D8-DCAD0F0CCEAD
CrashReporter Key:   f8d3c65b5d8546e16be90ff79e7f7852d1d340d6
Hardware Model:      iPod5,1
Process:             app [3639]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A3BB04D-C783-432C-81D8-9FD17E3E766C/myapp.app/myapp
Identifier:          it.myapp
Version:             1.0.2 (1.0.2)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-08-11 13:16:33.319 +0200
Launch Time:         2015-08-11 13:12:22.777 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
it.myapp failed to scene-update in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 17.490 (user 17.490, system 0.000), 85% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 15.755, 77% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos
Thread 0:
0   vImage                          0x28081984 conv4_8_A + 300
1   vImage                          0x2807e6c4 vConvolveCore_Planar8 + 2052
2   vImage                          0x2804ed8a __vImageConvolveWithBias_Planar8_block_invoke + 138
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fc8ee0 _dispatch_client_callout2 + 20
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fd3b76 _dispatch_apply_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 146
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fd3f56 dispatch_apply_f$VARIANT$mp + 538
6   vImage                          0x2804ecc6 vImageConvolveWithBias_Planar8 + 714
7   vImage                          0x2804e9f0 vImageConvolve_Planar8 + 76
8   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x298d8d06 symmetric_convolve + 582
9   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x298d893a RIPLayerSymmetricConvolve + 522
10  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x298d86b0 RIPLayerGaussianBlur + 336
11  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x298d81ae rips_s_BltShapeShadow + 438
12  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x298dd49e rips_s_BltShape + 46
13  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x298cc9e4 ripc_Render + 196
14  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x298da6d0 ripc_DrawPath + 200
15  CoreGraphics                    0x2959f260 CGContextDrawPath + 140
16  WebCore                         0x346ad300 WebCore::GraphicsContext::fillPath(WebCore::Path const&) + 120
17  WebCore                         0x3499706e WebCore::GraphicsContext::fillRectWithRoundedHole(WebCore::FloatRect const&, WebCore::FloatRoundedRect const&, WebCore::Color const&, WebCore::ColorSpace) + 230
18  WebCore                         0x34dca392 WebCore::RenderBoxModelObject::paintBoxShadow(WebCore::PaintInfo const&, WebCore::LayoutRect const&, WebCore::RenderStyle const&, WebCore::ShadowStyle, bool, bool) + 2258
19  WebCore                         0x3464db72 WebCore::RenderBox::paintBoxDecorations(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 534
20  WebCore                         0x3464bdc2 WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 214
21  WebCore                         0x3464d636 WebCore::RenderBlock::paint(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 206
22  WebCore                         0x3464bbe8 WebCore::RenderLayer::paintBackgroundForFragments(WTF::Vector<WebCore::LayerFragment, 1ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow> const&, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::LayoutRect const&, bool, WebCore::RenderLayer::LayerPaintingInfo const&, unsigned int, WebCore::RenderObject*) + 216
23  WebCore                         0x3464aeba WebCore::RenderLayer::paintLayerContents(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::RenderLayer::LayerPaintingInfo const&, unsigned int) + 1282
24  WebCore                         0x346fce08 WebCore::RenderLayerBacking::paintIntoLayer(WebCore::GraphicsLayer const*, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::IntRect const&, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 268
25  WebCore                         0x34df0592 WebCore::RenderLayerBacking::paintContents(WebCore::GraphicsLayer const*, WebCore::GraphicsContext&, unsigned int, WebCore::FloatRect const&) + 934
26  WebCore                         0x34998624 WebCore::GraphicsLayer::paintGraphicsLayerContents(WebCore::GraphicsContext&, WebCore::FloatRect const&) + 100
27  WebCore                         0x34d83c94 WebCore::PlatformCALayer::drawLayerContents(CGContext*, WebCore::PlatformCALayer*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::FloatRect, 5ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>&) + 328
28  WebCore                         0x346fcc5c -[WebLayer drawInContext:] + 108
29  QuartzCore                      0x2c2280be CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2066
30  QuartzCore                      0x2c309b48 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 48
31  QuartzCore                      0x2c2278a2 x_blame_allocations + 86
32  QuartzCore                      0x2c227550 CA::Layer::display_() + 1152
33  WebCore                         0x34fe10c6 -[WebSimpleLayer display] + 50
34  QuartzCore                      0x2c20bb18 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 196
35  QuartzCore                      0x2c20b7dc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 20
36  QuartzCore                      0x2c20b1c2 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 218
37  QuartzCore                      0x2c20afcc CA::Transaction::commit() + 320
38  UIKit                           0x2ca302ea _UIWindowUpdateVisibleContextOrder + 206
39  UIKit                           0x2ca3017c +[UIWindow _prepareWindowsPassingTestForAppResume:] + 12
40  UIKit                           0x2ca53792 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1110
41  UIKit                           0x2ca5310a __88-[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 114
42  UIKit                           0x2ca5308e -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 358
43  UIKit                           0x2ca4834a -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 470
44  FrontBoardServices              0x2fa7e1e8 __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 36
45  FrontBoardServices              0x2fa8d0de __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 10
46  CoreFoundation                  0x2930960a __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 10
47  CoreFoundation                  0x293088cc __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 212
48  CoreFoundation                  0x29307426 __CFRunLoopRun + 1710
49  CoreFoundation                  0x2925497c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
50  CoreFoundation                  0x2925478e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
51  GraphicsServices                0x3060604c GSEventRunModal + 132
52  UIKit                           0x2c84697c UIApplicationMain + 1436
53  myapp                       0x0009dc66 main (main.m:32)
54  libdyld.dylib                   0x37001aac start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370b32c8 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fd5e44 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 276
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fd5b76 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370b3518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370b330c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x29308ba6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2930716c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2925497c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2925478e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   CFNetwork                       0x28e099da +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 482
7   Foundation                      0x2a054996 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145e64 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145dd6 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370c6ba8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37144036 _pthread_mutex_lock + 390
2   WebCore                         0x3462752c _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 104
3   WebCore                         0x346274aa WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 42
4   CoreFoundation                  0x29309622 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
5   CoreFoundation                  0x29306d04 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2930704e __CFRunLoopRun + 726
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2925497c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2925478e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
9   WebCore                         0x3462624c RunWebThread(void*) + 412
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145e64 _pthread_body + 136
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145dd6 _pthread_start + 114
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370c6b38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x371453dc _pthread_cond_wait + 516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x371462ac pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x3622efa4 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 32
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2a515f96 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 210
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2a51244c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145e64 _pthread_body + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145dd6 _pthread_start + 114
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370c6b38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x371453dc _pthread_cond_wait + 516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x371462ac pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x3622efa4 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 32
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2a6dab60 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 100
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2a6dabc4 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 48
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x2a51244c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145e64 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145dd6 _pthread_start + 114
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370b3518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370b330c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x29308ba6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2930716c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2925497c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2925478e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x3464f558 WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 288
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x2a51244c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145e64 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145dd6 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370b3568 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fd34e6 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 186
2   MediaToolbox                    0x2ad0a43e fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1962
3   CoreMedia                       0x29aaee74 figThreadMain + 184
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145e64 _pthread_body + 136
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145dd6 _pthread_start + 114
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370b3518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370b330c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x29308ba6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2930716c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2925497c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2925478e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x27f783e8 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 128
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x27f6a8e4 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 192
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145e64 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145dd6 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370c6b38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x371453dc _pthread_cond_wait + 516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x371462ac pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2a5160da WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 58
4   WebCore                         0x34ec1756 std::__1::unique_ptr<WTF::Function<void ()>, std::__1::default_delete<WTF::Function<void ()> > > WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessage()::'lambda'(WTF::Function<void ()> const&)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessage()::'lambda'(WTF::Function<void ()> const&)&&, double) + 70
5   WebCore                         0x346e4cd2 WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 150
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x2a51244c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145e64 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145dd6 _pthread_start + 114
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370c708c __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2930d32e __CFSocketManager + 486
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145e64 _pthread_body + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145dd6 _pthread_start + 114
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  WebCore: File
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370c6b38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x371453dc _pthread_cond_wait + 516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x371462ac pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2a5160da WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 58
4   WebCore                         0x34934394 std::__1::unique_ptr<WebCore::FileThread::Task, std::__1::default_delete<WebCore::FileThread::Task> > WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::FileThread::Task>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::FileThread::Task>::waitForMessage()::'lambda'(WebCore::FileThread::Task const&)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::FileThread::Task>::waitForMessage()::'lambda'(WebCore::FileThread::Task const&)&&, double) + 68
5   WebCore                         0x349341b2 WebCore::FileThread::runLoop() + 154
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x2a51244c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145e64 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37145dd6 _pthread_start + 114
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370c79cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143e9c _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 13 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos
Thread 13:
0   vImage                          0x28081960 conv4_8_A + 264
1   vImage                          0x2807e6c4 vConvolveCore_Planar8 + 2052
2   vImage                          0x2804ed8a __vImageConvolveWithBias_Planar8_block_invoke + 138
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fd3b76 _dispatch_apply_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 146
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fd22d6 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 846
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x36fd31f6 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 102
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143e22 _pthread_wqthread + 666
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37143b74 start_wqthread + 4

No thread state (register information) available
Binary Images:
0x97000 - 0x10afff myapp armv7  <5c3f62bd3a073ae28638f130eb45dee1> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A3BB04D-C783-432C-81D8-9FD17E3E766C/myapp.app/myapp
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find out the reason behind `XPCErrorDescription`?

Comment: Any luck here OP or @AsadPalekar?  I think I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I figured out my issue.  I am using cordova, and I was rendering a button with box-shadow that apparently the graphics engine couldn't handle.  Removing the box-shadow css on my element got rid of this crash for me.  Hopefully this helps others!